# Angular ngInclude example: Replace select drop down with buttons

Tags: angularjs

I am working on [this](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angInclude) example.. What is the best way to replace the `<select>` with `<button>` and still keep the functionality?

**I tried:**

```
    <div ng-model="template" ng-repeat="t in templates">
       <button>{{t.name}}</button>
    </div>
```

Rendering the buttons work but switching between templates does not work

**Original code:**

```
<select ng-model="template" ng-options="t.name for t in templates">
     <option value="">(blank)</option>
 </select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
 <div ng-repeat="t in templates">
   <button ng-click="setTemplate(t)">{{t.name}}</button>
 </div>
```

And add this to the controller:

```
$scope.setTemplate = function(t){
   $scope.template = t;     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-click on the button to set the `$scope.template`:

```
<div ng-model="template" ng-repeat="t in templates">
    <button ng-click="template=t">{{t.name}}</button>
</div>
```